# Limit of sequence and Riemann sum

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(k-1)^7}{n^8}$$

So,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(k-1)^7}{n^8} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}(\frac{k}{n}-\frac{1}{n})^7$$

But how to get the rid of $-\frac{1}{n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^7=\int_0^1x^7dx=\left.\frac{x^8}{8}\right|_0^1=\frac{1}{8}$$

Comment: There are a few subtleties going on here. The OP would be well-served to identify them. Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Instead of keeping it as $\left(\frac{k}{n}-\frac{1}{n}\right)^7$, you could just work with $\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)^7$.